# Download PDF From API Request To File Cabinet In SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Anyone know if it is possible to send a request to an API that returns a Content-Type of `application/pdf` and save that PDF to the file cabinet in NetSuite?

I'm writing this in a Suitelet like below. This is fully runnable, just make sure to change the folder ID.

```js
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType Suitelet
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
* author: Me
* Date: 06/15/2019
* Version: 1.0
*/
define(["N/log", "N/https", "N/file"], function (log, https, file) {
    function onRequest(ctx) {
        if (ctx.request.method === 'GET') {

            // Request the PDF
            var pdfResp = https.get({ url: 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf' });
            log.debug('PDF Response', pdfResp.body);
            // output: %PDF-1.4 %äüöß 2 0 obj <> stream x�=�� 1E...

            // Save the PDF to File Cabinet
            var pdfFileObj = file.create({
                name: 'sample.pdf',
                fileType: file.Type.PDF,
                contents: pdfResp.body,
                folder: 107, // <--- change this to your own folder id
            });
            var createdFileId = pdfFileObj.save();

            // Send back the ID
            ctx.response.write(createdFileId);
        }
    }
    return { onRequest: onRequest };
});
```

This produces an unexpected suitescript error on the file.create line. I have experimented with using the encode module to try to convert the response to base 64 but the best that does is create a blank pdf. I can make this same request in Postman, for example, and download the file just fine so I know that data is correct. Something with the encoding seems incorrect and doesn't allow me to save the file correctly.

Comment: I am doing the same thing (pdf from API) but receive the pdf already in Base64, so I can put it directly into file contents. Any chance you can specify how you want to receive the pdf?

Comment: You can achieve the same results (empty pdf file) without the encoding by making the fileType PLAINTEXT but giving the name .pdf extension. You can see the contents of the file by giving it a .txt extension and opening in a text editor.

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but did you get this working? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @AnishP NetSuite is not able to save pure binary data to the file cabinet (which is what is happening in this example). Depending on the header in the response NetSuite will auto convert the binary to base64 text, which is then able to be stored in the file cabinet just like the example. I don't remember all the supported content types but I think application/octet-stream was one of them.